# Textureview get Surface

Tags: android, exoplayer

I am using the ExoPlayer Library, which expects a Surface, however i couldn't find any Method, which retrieves the underlying Surface of the Textureview. Any Ideas?

The Surfaceview has a method for that:

```
surfaceView.getHolder().getSurface()
```

Or is there no surface in TextureView?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First step is to get the SurfaceTexture from the [TextureView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TextureView.html) using the [getSurfaceTexture()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TextureView.html#getSurfaceTexture%28%29) member function.

```
SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture = textureView.getSurfaceTexture();
```

Then create the Surface object from the constructor [Surface(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Surface.html#Surface%28android.graphics.SurfaceTexture%29) that will accept the SurfaceTexture from your TextureView object.

```
Surface surface = new Surface(surfaceTexture);
```

For more information take a look at [this issue report](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/98). It confirms that by constructing the Surface object in the manner I described it is possible to use the Surface from a TextureView with ExoPlayer.

Comment: Hey thank you, i had it this way, and still the app steps into an exception, is there anything else i have to add like a listener?

Comment: I haven't used the ExoPlayer library, but you might need to implement the `TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener` to ensure the surface is valid before you try and access it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also now in the new versions add an "AnalyticsListener" to the "SimpleExoPlayer" instance, and implement the method "onRenderedFirstFrame" which has the surface as one of its parameters.