# 'WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE' Not working on ExoPlayer2 activity

Tags: android, exoplayer

We have a video player application that using ExoPlayer2. And its needs to be protected from the screen recorder.

We integrated the 'WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE' but some of the device is not supporting this feature ( Lenovo , Samsung etc ..) in ExoPlayer2 activity screen ,user can capture full video through 'DU Recorder'.

This is happening only ExoPlayer2 activity all other screens are working fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using a `SurfaceView` with ExopPlayer2, you can use [`SurfaceView.setSecure(true)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html#setSecure(boolean)) which will prevent the player from being recorded.

If you're not already using a `SurfaceView`, you can set one on the `SimpleExoPlayer` - you can see how that works by checking out this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49476176/how-to-use-textureview-instead-of-surfaceview-with-playerview-of-exoplayer/49478928#49478928). Or if you're interacting with Exo through something *other* than `SimpleExoPlayer`, then I'd bet there's a way to get access to the `SurfaceView` to call `setSecure` on it.

Let me know if that works or if you need any further clarification.