# Android - TextureView + SurfaceHolder.Callback

Tags: android, surfaceview, textureview

I wanted to know if it is possible to use SurfaceHolder.Callback (and of course its callbacks) in combination with TextureView?

I mean sth. like the following:

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements  SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private TextureView mTextureView;

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int format, int width, int height) {

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {

    }
}
```

Would that be working? The reason I ask is that whenever I see SurfaceHolder.Callback, they use SurfaceView.

Answer (score 1):

No you can't. For **TextureView** you should use **SurfaceTextureListener**. In many senses these callbacks are similar to **SurfaceHolder** callbacks.

For example, instead of

```
@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
    mPreviewSurface = holder.getSurface();
}
```

you can write

```
@Override
public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture texture, int width, int height) {
    mPreviewSurface = new Surface(texture);
}
```

See https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/98. Thanks to [@BrentM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30972268/192373).